# Class properties in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, class, properties, ecmascript-6

I need to declare some properties for my class but this does not work:

```
class MyClass {
  var property1; //<--error raised!
  var property2;

  constructor(prop1,prop2) {
    this.property1 = prop1;
    this.property2 = prop2;
  }
}
```

It seems ECMAScript 6 has no class property declaration yet? I'm using NodeJS 4.x which supports ECMAScript 6.

**Updated**:
ES6 stage 3 now has public & private properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations

Comment: Note that node.js 4.x is only supporting a small subset of ECMAScript 6. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: If you are willing to add a build step you could use Babel with [a plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) for transforming class properties. This would allow you to use a syntax very similar to what you're currently trying.

Comment: The assignments in your constructor totally suffice. There's no need - and no way - to "declare" instance properties in the class in JavaScript.

Comment: i need to reopen this question, ES6 stage 3 update has public property & private property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations